# visualEffectView darker on device with localization

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, uivisualeffectview

I have what appears to be a strange effect.

I'm using `UIVisualEffectView` as a background for a `UILabel`. The blur style is set to light.

On two identical devices the same version of app running shows a very different opacity for the `UIVisualEffectView`.

The only difference is the two devices localization.  The device which is set to Japanese language has a much darker background `UIVisualEffectView` than the device set to English.

I did not see anywhere in the docs that the `UIVisualEffectView` will differ for different localizations.

Or maybe there is another issue I have not found?  The `UIVisualEffectView` is in a `tableViewHeaderFooterView` for a `tableView` header. The view only contains a `UIVisualEffectView` and a `UILabel`. The label is placed over the `UIVisualEffectView`. The only thing that is set is the text of the `UILabel`.

Edit 1

I have tried different localizations with the simulator and in all cases the `UIVisualEffectView` is the same consistent and correct background color/opacity.

Is there any setting on an individual `iPhone` that would cause the `UIVisualEffectView` to be darker?

Comment: Please go to Settings > General > Accessabilty and match the settings forte different devices. Then Compare localization, this weird it should not get effected by this method.

Comment: Go to `Settings`>`General`>`Accessibility`>`Increase Contrast`>`Reduce Transparency`. Check if the switch is on. If the switch is on, UIVisualEffectView does not make visual effect (No Blur I mean). If the switch is off, there will be blur as normal. As I believe, it has nothing to do with localisation.